# TCP server is closing connections

Tags: python

I have this code

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        _data = self.request.recv(1024)

        Utils.log("Received from %s: %s" % (self.client_address, _data))
```

calling it with

```
kamcon_server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, 3011), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)

server_thread = threading.Thread(target = kamcon_server.serve_forever)
server_thread.setDaemon(True)
server_thread.start()
```

I can connect to the host, and the server can send the data, but when the client sends something to the server, the connection is automatically closed. Why? Thank you.

Comment: Or do you recommend to use twisted when there is no serious and intensive traffic ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `handle()` method is only calling `recv()` once per connection.  If you want to handle multiple messages from the client, you need to loop.  You should think about your protocol as well, so that you can handle request/response messages larger than 1024 bytes (e.g. parse `_data` and figure out if you have a complete message, buffer partial requests, etc).

For example:

```
def handle(self):
    close = 0
    while not close:
        _data = self.request.recv(1024)
        if not _data:
            # EOF, client closed, just return
            return
        Utils.log("Received from %s: %s" % (self.client_address, _data))
        self.request.send('got %d bytes\r\n' % len(_data))
        if 'quit' in _data:
            close = 1
```

Client session:

```
% telnet localhost 3011
hi
got 4 bytes
bye
got 5 bytes
telnet> quit
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, it allows multiple connections to same port and not close socket until client do it:

```
import SocketServer
import socket, threading

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
        BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
        def handle(self):
                while 1:
                        #get input with wait if no data
                        data = self.request.recv(self.BUFFER_SIZE)
                        #suspect many more data (try to get all - without stop if no data)
                        if (len(data)==self.BUFFER_SIZE):
                                while 1:
                                        try: #error means no more data
                                                data += self.request.recv(self.BUFFER_SIZE, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)
                                        except:
                                                break
                        #no data found exit loop (posible closed socket)
                        if (data == ""): break

                        #processing input
                        print "%s (%s) wrote: %s" % (self.client_address[0], threading.currentThread().getName(), data.strip())

if __name__ == "__main__":
        HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
        server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
```

You can also use ForkingTCPServer instead ThreadingTCPServer.

Answer (score 1):

the handle() method is called once a new TCP connection is set up, not once every time there is data available. You're supposed to handle all comminication of a TCP session in this method.

Since all you do is read one chunk of data, the connection getst closed when the handle() method returns.

Answer (score 0):

Look into how TCP connections work, at the end of every 'Stream' of TCP data the connection is closed, to tell the listener that no more data is incoming in that batch. Roughly a TCP connection is as follows:

1. Open Connection
2. Send Data
3. Close Connection

If you're just looking at sending packets of data, try using UDP instead that way each packet will be read on arrival, provided you're listening for it.

It might be worth telling us what your planning on using this server for...

Anyway hope that helps.